# Prevent office 365 Outlook from removing line breaks

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

Outlook has an annoying misfeature that removes line breaks from plain text email. In desktop outlook, you can disable the offending behavior with [a message formatting option](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/287816/line-breaks-are-removed-in-posts-made-in-plain-text-format-in-outlook). I cannot find the equivalent option in Office 365's version of Outlook. Where is it?

Comment: Are you sure you are experiencing this problem with Office 365 Outlook? I have mine connected to my Gmail and switch to plain text for sent messages and tested and sent plain with line breaks and when I opened from another client machine, the line breaks were still there.

Comment: Do you mean the "Remove extra line breaks in plain text messages" option under File > Options > Mail? The option is still available in my Outlook 365 ProPlus. What's the specific version number of Outlook you are using? Are you using a latest build?

Comment: @stevefan: Yes, that is the option I'm looking for, except I have no file menu so far as I can tell; nor can I find a version number anywhere. It's a company-provided web version of Outlook and nothing is where I expect it to be.

Comment: @Andrew I thought you use the Outlook desktop version available for your Office 365 plan. With Outlook Online app, there is no such an option.

Answer (score 0):

In my version of outlook this can be disabled under

```
File (top left)
> Options (bottom left)
> Mail 
> Message format (scroll down to bottom)
> [ ] Remove extra line breaks...
```